# Embedded html style not affecting table?

Tags: html, css, html-table

I am trying to use style to affect the spacing of cells in my html table.
I am trying to use margin to make my cells have spacing on the right side only.
What am I doing wrong and how can I use style to affect cell spacing?

```
<html>
  <head>
    <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html;charset=ISO-8859-1">

<style>
body {
  font-family: Verdana, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  font-size: 9pt;
}

table {
  font-family: Verdana, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  font-size: 9pt;
}

td {
  margin: 0px 20px 0px 0px;
  color: #585858;
}

a {
  color: #326ea1;
}
</style>

    <title>Request</title>
  </head>
  <body>

    <table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
      <tbody>
        <tr>
          <td> Request ID </td>
          <td>516<br>
          </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Assigned<br>
          </td>
          <td>Fred Flintstone<br>
          </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Requestor<br>
          </td>
          <td>Bugs Bunny<br>
          </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Type<br>
          </td>
          <td>Construction<br>
          </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Location<br>
          </td>
          <td>Brazil<br>
          </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td> <br>
          </td>
          <td> <br>
          </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td style=" vertical-align: top;">Description</td>
          <td>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, <br>
              sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore <br>
              magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud <br>
              exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. 
          </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td><br>
          </td>
          <td><br>
          </td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>

  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, table cells do not have a margin property, but you can probably set a padding on them to get the desired behaviour. W3Schools has a page on styling tables that might help you here: http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_table.asp

If you change your code to the following, it should work:

```
td {
 padding: 0px 20px 0px 0px;
 color: #585858;
}
```

You can also set a cellspacing attribute on the table. That will put space *between* the cell borders - however, this affects the spacing around all sides of the cells.

Comment: that was quick and easy!  THANKS